# How to cache nested routes using Vue router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, service-worker, vue-router

I'm making an app in `Vue.js` with the `vue router`. I implemented the [offline-plugin](https://github.com/NekR/offline-plugin) and it works fine. But is there any option to cache the nested routes?

For example when I reload my app offline `/` or `/page1` routes are working but when I try to reload `/page1/child` or /page1/child/child I'm getting a blank page.

I used `cacheMaps` for now. Webpack conf.

```
new OfflinePlugin({
  cacheMaps: [
    {
      match: function (requestUrl) {
        return new URL('/', location)
      },
      requestTypes: ['navigate']
    }
  ]
})
```

Thanks.

Comment: `offline-plugin` will only cache your webpack assets; if your routes make HTTP requests then you will need to deal with that in order to make your app work properly offline (for example, by caching those requests).

Comment: For requests you mean request to my server when I wanna fetch something or?

Comment: Yes. Your app will require assets built by webpack (JS, CSS, images, etc), these are cached by offline-plugin; other requests that you make (with `fetch` or `$.ajax` or whatever) will not be cached by offline-plugin and will fail when you're offline. Check the network tab in dev tools for any failed requests and check for unhandled exceptions in the script debugger.

Comment: But I'm not fetching anything in that situation. I'm using `vue-router`and `router-link` for changing the route to show another vue component. I don't know how to get the nested routes offline.

Comment: Well then my advice doesn't apply; I said *if* your routes make HTTP requests.

Comment: No problem. Thanks anyway.